# Use SIM card slot as a smart card reader in Android phones

Tags: android, kernel, javacard, sim-card

I am working with Android phones that have 2 SIM card slots. I want to know if there is a way to use one of these slots to read another type of card, like JavaCards?

Comment: I want put a sam security card into phone . my phone have nfc reader and i want use phone as payment terminal for our mifare gift cards

Comment: Dear Saber, did you do it? Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

If your phone implements [SEEK for Android](http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/) open source stack, try enumerating the readers (you could have SIM1, SIM2). If you see 2 SIM readers, you're good to go. Honestly I think this is unlikely though, because Android's RIL interface is not designed to work with 2 SIMs.